# Handle Large number in Python

Tags: python

We have number "17179869184" which need to traverse. But we got memory error when we traverse into list. is there anyway we can handle similar kind of range number

```
for i in range(17179869184):
    print i

for i in xrange(17179869184):
    print i



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    for i in xrange(17179869184):
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

Comment: try `xrange` instead of `range`

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: Uh...did you read the question? :)

Comment: @Aशwiniचhaudhary: That's not a duplicate. Looks more like the exact opposite. `xrange()` iterates using a C long counter, and that fails with such gigantic numbers.

Comment: That said, 17 billion iterations are going to take a long time in any case. Are you sure you want to do this?

Comment: This is easily reproduced using:  `>>> list(xrange(sys.maxint-1, sys.maxint+1))`  which should be a list of just 3 numbers...

Comment: @TimPietzcker Well, it would take about 10 minutes, not exactly impossible.

Comment: FWIW, this is documented behavior.  See the Implementation Detail Note in the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#xrange)

Comment: @RamchandraApte: Did you time it? I tried it on my PC, and 16 minutes in, it had just crossed the 2**32 barrier (and I would except `+1` operations to be much slower on large integers than on 32bit integers).

Comment: @TimPietzcker I was just making a rough guess. And it fits within an order of magnitude; not bad for a rough guess (17179869184 is 4 times 2**32), so the time would be ~64 minutes (and maybe add another 20-30 minutes as increments would be slower as you said).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.count`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) with [`iter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#iter):

```
>>> from itertools import count
>>> c = count(0)
>>> for i in iter(c.next, 17179869184):
        #do something with i
```

Note that if you only want to loop that number of times, i.e you're not using `i` inside the loop then it will be better to use [`itertools.repeat`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat):

```
>>> from itertools import repeat
>>> for _ in repeat(None, 17179869184):
...     # do something here
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a while loop:

```
i=0
while i < 17179869184:
    # do stuff
    i += 1
```

If this is being done multiple times, create a Python implementation of range() using generators.

```
def py_range(num):
    i = 0
    while i < num:
        yield i
        i+=1
```

Well, `py_range()` not the same as `range()` as it has `start` and other arguments. But you can search online for a complete implementation (should be there).

Comment: +1, you should start iterating from 0, though. And don't forget to increment `i`...